# Disregard a strings' space characters in ASM

Tags: string, assembly

Trying to find the number of characters in a string and disregard all the " " space characters

I have a C++ portion that passes the strings to asm and here is my asm
works fine, only thing is that the space characters are being counted as well.

```
stringLength PROC PUBLIC
    PUSH    ebp             ; save caller base pointer
    MOV     ebp, esp        ; set our base pointer
    SUB     esp, (1 * 4)    ; allocate uint32_t local vars
    PUSH    edi
    PUSH    esi
    ; end prologue


    MOV esi, [ebp+8]            ;gets the string
    xor ebx, ebx

COMPARE:
    MOV al, [esi + ebx]     
    CMP al, 0               ;compare character of string with 0
    JE FINALE               ;if = to 0 go to end
    INC ebx                 ;counter
    CMP al, ' '             ;compare with sapce
    JE SPACE                ;go get rid of the space and keep going
    INC al                  ;otherwise inc al to next character and repeat
    JMP COMPARE             

SPACE:
    DEC ebx                 ;get rid of the extra space
    INC al
    JMP COMPARE             ;goes back to compare


FINALE:

    MOV eax,ebx         ; bring back the counter
    ADD esp, (2 * 4)    ; clear the stack
    POP esi 
    POP edi
    MOV esp, ebp        ; deallocate locals
    POP ebp             ; restore caller base pointer
RET

stringLength ENDP   ; end the procedure
END stringLength
```

Comment: The above code is counting the number of characters in a string.  If you want to count the number of characters disregarding spaces, ***you are going to have to at least first try.***  Stackoverflow is not a "write-my-homework-for-me" service.

Comment: I know, sorry if i came off as a "please do it" kind of person. Can I get a point in the right direction? Is the general way I'm going about it in the ball park?

Comment: Hint: Clean up your use and intent of `al` and `ebx` as your code reflects confusion

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of useless stuff and not doing anything to count ignoring the spaces.

1. You don't really need to setup a new stack frame, for such a simple routine you can do everything in clobbered registers, or at most save a few registers on the stack;
2. That `inc al` is pointless - you are incrementing *the character value*, just to discard it at the next loop iteration.
3. `push fmt` and then you clean the stack immediately? What sense does it make?
4. `mov ebx, 0`- nobody does that, the idiomatic way to zero a register is `xor ebx,ebx` (the instruction encoding is more compact);
5. `cmp al, 0` given that you are only interested in equality, you can just do `test al, al` (more compact);
6. you read [ebp+12] but never actually use it - is that supposed to be an unused parameter?

As for the algorithm itself, you'll just have to keep a separate counter to count non-space characters; actually, you can just keep `ebx` for that, and increment directly `esi` to iterate over characters. For example:

```
    xor ebx, ebx
COMPARE:
    mov al, [esi] 
    cmp al, ' ' 
    jne nonspace
    inc ebx
nonspace:
    test al, al
    jz FINALE 
    inc esi
    jmp COMPARE 
FINALE:
```

Now, this can be streamlined further exploiting the fact that the `eax` is going to be the return value, and that you can clobber freely `ecx` and `edx`, so:

```
stringLength PROC PUBLIC
    mov ecx,[esp+4]         ; get the string
    xor eax,eax             ; zero the counter
compare:
    mov dl,[ecx]            ; read character
    cmp dl,' '
    jne nospace
    inc eax                 ; increase counter if it's a space
nospace:
    test dl,dl
    jz end                  ; go to end if we reached the NUL
    inc ecx                 ; next character
    jmp compare
end:
    ret                     ; straight return, nothing else to do
stringLength ENDP   ; end the procedure
```

---

*edit*: about the updated version

```
COMPARE:
    MOV al, [esi + ebx]     
    CMP al, 0
    JE FINALE
    INC ebx
    CMP al, " "     ; I don't know what assembler you are using,
                    ; but typically character values are in single quotes
    JE SPACE
    INC al          ; this makes no sense! you are incrementing
                    ; the _character value_, not the position!
                    ; it's going to be overwritten at the next iteration
    JMP COMPARE             

SPACE:
    INC eax         ; you cannot use eax as a counter, you are already
                    ; using it (al) as temporary store for the current
                    ; character!
    JMP COMPARE
```

Comment: I cleaned up some of the garbage i had, I don't want to use test because we haven't learned that in class. I also just updated what i have so far with a small function to get rid of the extra " " character yet it doesn't get rid of it.

Comment: I added commentary about the new version; you seem to have some confusion about `eax` - `el` is the lower byte of `eax`, they are not separate registers, so you cannot use it both as a counter and as storage for the current character.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification of the two registers, that now makes some sense. However I Don't understand your comment about 'inc al' and how it increments the wrong thing. Doesn't al now hold '[esi + ebx]' ? also, if I decremented the ebx as shown in my newest edit would it still work? it doesn't currently work with some strings passed in from the c++ side but I don't see how it wouldn't logically work... I'm guessing it doesn't work because your 'al' statement

Comment: @Ryan: `al` holds a copy of *the value* stored at `[esi+ebx]`, as in, if it's a letter `'a'` `al` will contain the value 97; if you increment `al` the `'a'` will become a `'b'`, but it won't matter, because at the next iteration you are going to reload it again. What moves that loop forward is not the `inc al`, but the `inc ebx`. Notice also that, even if it was as you imagined, it would still be wrong, because `al` is an 8 bit sub-register, so it would overflow to 0 after 255, instead of going forward to the next address.

Comment: Okay that makes sense but how does it traverse along the string? that's probably the last thing i am confused on now. If I had a string `abcdef` what makes it go through to the last string. after each iteration of the loop does `[esi+eb]` automatically go up to the next character?

Comment: It's not automatic, you are manually incrementing `ebx`! It's `inc ebx` that is moving you forward, not `inc al`.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to use whole the `eax` register to compare values. In such manner:

```
; inlet data:
; eax - pointer to first byte of string
; edx - count of bytes in string
; ecx - result (number of non-space chars)
              push esi
              mov ecx, 0
              mov esi, eax
@@compare:    cmp edx, 4
              jl @@finalpass
              mov eax, [esi]
              xor eax, 20202020h  ; 20h - space char
              cmp al, 0
              jz @@nextbyte0
              inc ecx
@@nextbyte0:  cmp ah, 0
              jz @@nextbyte1
              inc ecx
@@nextbyte1:  shr eax, 16
              cmp al, 0
              jz @@nextbyte2
              inc ecx
@@nextbyte2:  cmp ah, 0
              jz @@nextbyte3
              inc ecx
@@nextbyte3:  add esi, 4
              sub edx, 4
              jmp @@compare
@@finalpass:  and edx, edx
              jz @@fine
              mov al, [esi]
              cmp al, 20h
              jz  @@nextbyte4
              inc ecx
@@nextbyte4:  inc esi
              dec edx
              jmp @@finalpass
@@fine:       pop esi
; save the result data and restore stack
```